# Primefaces PDF display issue in IE 9

Tags: primefaces

I'm using Primefaces dialog to display pdf file through  tag which invokes a servlet to write pdf stream.
The dialog has a minimizable option true,when I click minimize and if I maximize the dialog  pdf content is getting lost in IE9

I'm unable to figure out the issue,Can any one please share your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

IE is not a web-kit browser, some things work but some components behave crazy in IE. You can use firefox or chrome, all time updated browsers.

Comment: Hi meyquel thanks for your suggestion but for our applicationthe IE9 is the primary browser